# Joining back on the same table in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below

[image]

And the output I require is

[image: Output]

The match is defined on the basis of PO number. If PO number exists in both the sources then it should be **match** else **only in AAP** and **only in SNW** respectively. Can this be achieved?

Thanks,
Ani

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: SELECT *

 FROM @T WHERE PO IN (
    SELECT a.PO FROM @T a
    JOIN @T b on b.PO = a.PO AND b.SOURCE <> a.SOURCE
)
I tried this but it gives me the matching rows but I am not understanding how to add the third row with the help of case statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *,
    case when min(SOURCE) over (partition by ID) <> max(SOURCE) over (partition by ID)
        then 'Match' else 'Only in ' + SOURCE end as Status
from T
```

or

```
select *,
    case when exists
    (
        select 1 from T t2
        where t2.ID = T.ID and t2.SOURCE <> T.SOURCE
    )
        then 'Match' else 'Only in ' + SOURCE end as Status
```

Comment: Hi @shawnt00 
Thank you so much for your answer. I tried using the query provided by you. But for PO number 3 it is also giving a match.

Comment: @Anish I re-read the question and added the `partition by ID` part.